# How to save function output in R into workload directly without displaying it?

Tags: r

I am writing a function in R like this:

```
MH <- function(Nsim,var,initial) {
Total <- 0
X=rep(runif(1),Nsim)
X[1]=initial                                                          
for (i in 2:Nsim){
  Y=X[i-1]+rnorm(1, mean=0, sd=sqrt(var))
  alpha= fx(Y)/fx(X[i-1])
  u <- runif(1)
  X[i]=X[i-1]+(Y-X[i-1])*(u<alpha)
  Total=Total+as.numeric(u<alpha)
  }
  accept=Total/Nsim
  accept
}
```

I want my function output to be 'accept' while saving the vector X into the workspace directly without displaying it so that I can do things with X later. 
I know this is a basic question but could someone help me with this?

Comment: Do you mean you want to directly assign the value of "accept" to an object named "X" in your workspace?

Comment: @AnandaMahto Nope. What I mean is that in my function X is a vector to be generated, however it can be huge so I want it to be saved to workspace directly without displaying it, while in the same time letting "accept" to be my function output.

Comment: What about returning a list that contains both accept and X? If the issue is that you don't want X to be printed then you could write a custom print function...

Comment: @Dason I've thought of returning a list as my output but could you explain more about using the custom print function? Sry I'm really new to R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this

```
MH <- function(Nsim,var,initial) {
Total <- 0
X=rep(runif(1),Nsim)
X[1]=initial                                                          
for (i in 2:Nsim){
  Y=X[i-1]+rnorm(1, mean=0, sd=sqrt(var))
  alpha= fx(Y)/fx(X[i-1])
  u <- runif(1)
  X[i]=X[i-1]+(Y-X[i-1])*(u<alpha)
  Total=Total+as.numeric(u<alpha)
  }
  accept=Total/Nsim

  # put output into a list and give it class MH
  output <- list(accept = accept, X = X)
  class(output) <- "MH"
  output
}

# Write a custom print function for objects of
# class "MH"
print.MH <- function(x, ...){
  print(x[["accept"]])
}

out <- MH(10, 1, 1)
out # only prints the acceptance rate
out$accept # but can access accept
out$X # and X individually
```